# R Shiny: Control checkbox value with action button

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to be able to control the value of a checkbox also by clicking an action button (for disabling certain program options when one selects a different functionality). Though I got close to what I want, I cannot get the checkbox properly initialized. The action button has to be pressed at least once to get see the checkbox in the first place.

MWE:

```
# server.R

function(input, output) {

    output$make_box <- renderUI({
      checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Choice A", value = setboxon())
    })

    setboxon <- eventReactive(input$action, {
      if(is.null(input$checkbox))
        return(FALSE)
      else if(input$checkbox==TRUE)
        return(FALSE)
      else
        return(TRUE)
    })

    # check status off checkbox value
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkbox })

}
```

and

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(

# plot checkbox
uiOutput("make_box"),

# plot action button
actionButton("action", label = "Action"),
br(),

hr(),
# output check
fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a `reactiveVal()`:

```
setboxon <- reactiveVal(TRUE)

observe({
  if(is.null(input$checkbox))
    setboxon(FALSE)
  else if(input$checkbox==FALSE)
    setboxon(FALSE)
})

observe({
  if(input$action) setboxon(TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I only changed the last `observe` function to an `observeEvent` that contains an `if` statement that let you set the value back to `FALSE` as well.